# sort polars df column values based upon user-defined custom order

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I am trying to custom sort the values of a polars df column

See example below:

```
df = pl.DataFrame( 
     { 
      "a": [1, 2, None], 
      "b": [6.0, 5.0, 4.0], 
      "c": ["a", "c", "b"], 
     }
 )

print (df)

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
│ 2    ┆ 5.0 ┆ c   │
│ null ┆ 4.0 ┆ b   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘

sort_list = ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

expected output

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2    ┆ 5.0 ┆ c   │
│ null ┆ 4.0 ┆ b   │
│ 1    ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I tried the string cache method, but it is not working and I am not too familiar with this method to even know, if I am doing it right to begin with.

tried the below

```
with pl.StringCache(): 
    pl.Series(sort_list).cast(pl.Categorical) 
    df1 = df.with_columns(
         pl.col("c").cast(pl.Categorical) 
         )
print (df1)
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ cat │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
│ 2    ┆ 5.0 ┆ c   │
│ null ┆ 4.0 ┆ b   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Any input is much appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a new [`pl.Enum`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/api/polars.Enum.html#polars.Enum) type in Polars.

- "*When the categories are known up front use `Enum`."*
  <sup>https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-types/categoricals/#enum-vs-categorical</sup>

```py
df.sort(pl.col("c").cast(pl.Enum(["c", "b", "a"])))
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2    ┆ 5.0 ┆ c   │
│ null ┆ 4.0 ┆ b   │
│ 1    ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I like this solution as it is much more straightforward than using string cache method and accomplishes the task in single line. thanks

Answer (score 1):

forgot to call the sort method after the string cache method which fixes my sort issue.

```
df1=df1.sort('c')
print (df1)
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ cat │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2    ┆ 5.0 ┆ c   │
│ null ┆ 4.0 ┆ b   │
│ 1    ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to:

Create **your_order** dictionary with value and its index

```
sort_list = ['c', 'b', 'a']
your_order = {v: idx for idx, v in enumerate(sort_list)}
#{'c': 0, 'b': 1, 'a': 2}
```

Sort with respected to column `'c'` using `map_dict(your_order)`

```
final = df.sort(pl.col("c").map_dict(your_order))

print(final)
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ f64 ┆ cat │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2    ┆ 5.0 ┆ c   │
│ null ┆ 4.0 ┆ b   │
│ 1    ┆ 6.0 ┆ a   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```